# Why is it "wonderfully" instead of "wonderful"?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

Why is it "wonderfully" instead of "wonderful"? As far as I know adverbs are not usually used with such words as "look", "feel", etc. It's "you look beautiful", not "you look beautifully". So is "wonderfully" used to emphasize "like"? I'm a bit confused.

*"Within forty minutes her head was covered with tiny, close-lying curls that made her look wonderfully like a truant schoolboy".*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the sentence

> Within forty minutes her head was covered with tiny, close-lying curls that made her look wonderfully like a truant schoolboy

*wonderfully* isn't modifying *like*, it's modifying *look*.  She didn't look "wonderful, like a schoolboy", she looked "*amazingly like* a schoolboy".